# Why is premium processing available on only certain USCIS immigration forms and not all USCIS immigration forms?

Tags: usa, paperwork

I read on https://www.uscis.gov/forms/all-forms/how-do-i-request-premium-processing

> Premium processing provides expedited processing for Form I-129, Petition for Nonimmigrant Worker, and Form I-140, Immigrant Petition for Alien Worker. Specifically, we guarantee processing within 15 calendar days to those who choose to use this service, or we will refund the premium processing service fee and will continue with expedited processing.

Why is premium processing available on only certain USCIS immigration forms and not all USCIS immigration forms?

Comment: Or you might ask why premium processing is available for any forms at all. Why should someone be able to be processed ahead of others who filed earlier by paying more?

Comment: @user102008 same reason for why I have to pay to drive on the fast lane or get Global Entry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authority to collect additional fees for premium processing is provided by law in INA 286(u) ([8 USC 1356(u)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1356#u)), and the types of applications eligible are listed. The types of applications eligible for premium processing was recently expanded by the Emergency Stopgap USCIS Stabilization Act, and USCIS has published [a rule](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2022-06742) implementing this, but it doesn't take effect until May 31, 2022.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very interesting, and great statistical tables in the rule. Too bad that Form N-400 doesn't seem to be part of the new applications eligible for premium processing, unless I misread the rule.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the statute specifically lists employment-related benefits. While there's a "catch-all" provision that says "any other that the Secretary deems...", in practice it shows the Congress' intent to prioritize employment-based applications. For N400 there's already a waiting period of years and you should already be a permanent resident, so there's no urgency - no job position to fill, no foreigner to relocate. Why would there be a shortcut?

Comment: @littleadv because premium processing means more revenue for the government.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt USCIS fees fund USCIS, they do not provide revenue to the government.

Comment: @littleadv USCIS a government agency. Indeed they have their own budget.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt in theory, the premium processing fees pay for the cost of providing premium processing.  I suppose that the reality is close enough to the theory that an increase in applications for premium processing would bring little to no benefit to USCIS.  At least, that seems to me to be the most likely reason for USCIS not seeking to promote premium processing.  But an analysis of the economics and politics behind the design of the system is more likely to belong on [Politics.SE] than here.

Comment: @phoog good idea: [Why doesn't the USCIS offer premium processing for all its immigration forms?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/72864/2231)